# How can i pause a google script until a cell has numeric value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timeout, conditional-statements

While a script imports values from another sheet i want to pause the rest of the script.
When the cell c11 becomes a numeric value (import succeeded) i want the script to replace the formula with a "value only" copy-paste of the cells.
Instead of the numeric check a pause would also be a solution.
The next time i run the script i put back the import formula in the cells and so on..

Thx in advance

```
    function updateStartHierWaarden() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      spreadsheet.getRange('C10').activate();
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=importrange(verkoopfacturensysteem;"openstaandeFacturen!C2")');
      spreadsheet.getRange('C11').activate();
      var waarde = spreadsheet.getRange('C11').getValue();
      spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=importrange("bank";"saldo!a1")');
      var type = typeof waarde;


      if (type == "number") {
        spreadsheet.getRange('C10:C11').activate();
        spreadsheet.getRange('C10:C11').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
      }else{
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ui.alert('geen nummer');
      }


     /* Utilities.sleep(10000);
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert('10sec pause');
      if
      */
    }
```

Comment: You can use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` to apply all pending changes to the Google Sheet before the next line of code runs.  See documentation at: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#flush](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#flush)

Comment: Could you clarify your question?